# How to connect PushPlugin + Parse on cordova android

Tags: cordova, parse-platform, push-notification, cordova-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

Has anyone had any experience using the PushPlugin library (https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) on a Cordova app when using Parse.com as their notifications on android? I followed their readme, which registers for the GCM sender, but that never makes it back to Parse to know what ids to send the notifications to.

I've looked into using the parse plugin (https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin) just for the registering to parse, but I get the same error as this question: [Unable to instantiate receiver com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727676/unable-to-instantiate-receiver-com-parse-gcmbroadcastreceiver)

Has anyone had any luck using Parse and PushPlugin (or any other cordova notification plugin with Parse)? Specifically looking to make sure it can handle background notifications to run logic even when the app is closed

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are installing the plugin like I posted here -

[Parse/Parse.h file not found - Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355569/parse-parse-h-file-not-found-xcode-6/29387315#29387315)