# Parse/Parse.h file not found - Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, cordova, parse-platform, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I created project with cordova and ionic. I installed a Parse plugin (http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.parse.cordova.core.pushplugin).
When I open my project with Xcode I have an error:

> Parse/Parse.h file not found

I tried a lot of solutions found on stackoverflow, but none corrects my problem.

Framework Search Paths

> "MyApp/Plugins/com.parse.cordova.core.pushplugin"

Answer (score 1):

Try this plugin, it has updated Parse SDK framework.

https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin

Install the plugin like this (do not use Installation method url from README) -

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin.git

        OR

cordova plugin add https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin.git
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue and posted it on GitHub (https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin/issues/49).

My temporary workaround is:

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin
$ ionic platform rm ios
$ ionic platform add ios
```

XCode complains about the Parse.h file not found. It is in fact there. All I need to do is:

- open the project in XCode,
- go to General > Linked Frameworks and libraries
- remove, then add the Parse.framework from the same directory
- build

Actually, a better workaround is to make the Platform search path recursive, like so:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20856145/3889068