# How can PhoneGap/Ionic process push notifications from Parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework, phonegap-pushplugin

I can successfully push notifications to an app, and they show up on my Androids notifications, but I can't get the payload into the app.

I've found this plugin: [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin), but I can't seem to get it to work with Parse, since it asks for a GCM ID, and I don't know what to give it from Parse. Also, the plugin doesn't seem to offer a way to register to certain channels, or even get an installation ID from Parse.

If I include this plugin: [phonegap-parse-plugin](https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin) to take care of the installationID/channels stuff, then I get a runtime error that randomly pops up (adb logcat) saying it can't find `com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver`, and the app crashes.

I just want an Ionic app that can receive a push notification from Parse, and simply display it.

Comment: AFAIK, you can not use PushPlugin for accepting push notifications from Parse.

Comment: Try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29387315/1761793)

Comment: An android app can accept pushs from Parse, would there not be a way to make a plugin in java that could accept a push and send it into the javascript app?

Comment: That is very much possible. If you are up to it, you can make a plugin and use it for your project. Or better still, fix the issue in `phonegap-parse-plugin`.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same boat a week ago and trudging through it here's what I've found:

Here's the best fork I could find for the integrating with parse on cordova(ionic) on android and iOS

https://github.com/grrrian/phonegap-parse-plugin

---

1. Make sure to rename the `ionic plugin add` in the instructions to the `grrrian` repo not the `avivais` one in the READ.ME

   (He wanted to merge the branch, but I think avivais has finished maintaining it, so the PR is sitting dead)
2. There will be a compile error brought on by the new ionic Crosswalk feature which is trivial (heh.. ) to fix. Follow these instructions:

   https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/issues/426#issuecomment-113166439
3. Lastly, you need to create an Application Class manually as per the instructions. I didn't know how to do it so I made a comment here about it that should be helpful

   https://github.com/grrrian/phonegap-parse-plugin/issues/8#issuecomment-118955744

---

<del>I'm in the midst of trying to figure out why the notification isn't being received while its in the background though..</del>

Hope this helps someone

### EDIT:

Turns out it works fine in the background. All the notifications came in overnight. My thought is that Parse throttles if you send too many messages to one user at once